# LINQ Webservice GET list of similar products from JSON file

Tags: json, linq, web-services

I am loading a JSON file from a storage, that file hold similar products. One product can have multiple similar products. What i want to do is read the contents of the JSON file from the storage (code is de filename in this case: 458755), search in that file for a matching id_product and if that id_product if found return the list of the similar products. This is what i got so far:

```
string uriPath = "https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/";

public object GetSimilarProducts(string Code, int id_product)
{
 string secondPart = "api/SimilarProducts/" + Code + ".json";
 var allSimilarProducts = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(uriPath + secondPart);
 object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allSimilarProducts);

      var all = allSimilarProducts
      .Where(a => a.id_product == id_product)
      .ToList();

 return all;
}
```

This is a content sample of the SimilarProducts.json file: 458755.json

```
[
  {"id_product":33681,"Brand":"Ikea","Product":"STOCKHOLM Tv-meubel"},
  {"id_product":33681,"Brand":"Ikea","Product":"STOCKHOLM Kast"},
  {"id_product":33685,"Brand":"Ikea","Product":"EKENÄS Fauteuil"}
]
```

where it goes wrong is with the a =>.a_id_product because that normally reads from a database table. How would i be able to do this? Search in the JSON file and get all the two similar products of 33681 and output them as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for your products and then use Newtonsoft's `JsonConvert.Deserialize` to deserialize them in to a list of your products.

Here is a [working DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HNgykR) and code below:

Then you can complete your query for your results:

```
public List<Products> GetSimilarProducts(string Code, int id_product)
{

    var json =    @"[{ 'id_product':33681,'Brand':'Ikea','Product':'STOCKHOLM Tv-meubel'}, 
                        {'id_product':33681,'Brand':'Ikea','Product':'STOCKHOLM Kast'},
                        { 'id_product':33685,'Brand':'Ikea','Product':'EKENÄS Fauteuil'}]";                         

    (...other)

    var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Products>>(json);

    var all = products.Where(a => a.IdProduct == id_product).ToList();

    return all;

}


public class Products
{
    [JsonProperty("id_product")]
    public int IdProduct {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("Brand")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Product")]
    public string Product { get; set; }
}
```

Results:

[image]